# How to interact substrate node with reactjs frontend?

Tags: substrate-node-template, runtime, substrate-front-end

In ink! smart contract, we upload `.contract` file on chain and get the deployed contract address and use `metadata.json` file in frontend to interact with contract. Can someone tell me what's the procedures to interact with `substrate-node-template` runtime with react frontend? I found [`substrate-front-end-template`], It hasn't included any of the file from node that we generated while building.

**We are not using `substrate-front-end-template` we are building our own**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about the specific question you area asing here, so I am going to share with you some useful resources for building frontend substrate Dapps.

The [front-end-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-front-end-template) is the basic example, it uses ReactJS to render a web browser interface that enables you to interact with the Substrate-based blockchain node. It uses the [PolkadotJS tool](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/). Another framework you can use for interactions with Substrate chains is [CAPI](https://github.com/paritytech/capi).

[polkadot-js-api-ts-template](https://github.com/kianenigma/polkadot-js-api-ts-template) is a template that you can use to quickly start hacking in top of any substrate based chain, it creates for you all the basics.

Another example to interact with a substrate node you can look is: [Substrate Contracts UI](https://github.com/paritytech/contracts-ui). It is a web application for deploying and interacting with WASM smart contracts on Substrate blockchains that include the FRAME Contracts Pallet.

You can also take a look at the code of a production-ready frontend app: [Polkadot Staking Dashboard](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-staking-dashboard)

Other front end examples: [substrate-society](https://github.com/shawntabrizi/substrate-society), [chess-substrate-dapp](https://github.com/AlexD10S/chess-substrate-dapp) ...

Is good to see how the community is creating more front-end related tools, and example thet can be useful for you to interact with Smart Contracts from your frontend is [useInkathon](https://github.com/scio-labs/use-inkathon)

> Typesafe React Hooks abstracting functionality by polkadot.js for
> working with Substrate-based networks and ink! Smart Contracts.